# How can I get the Flag chosen by the user in my CLI

Tags: go, go-cobra

I have specified some flags like you can see below:

```
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "wallet", "w", "", "Specify the wallet to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "holding", "o", "", "Specify the holding to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "ticker", "t", "", "Specify the ticker to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "tag", "g", "", "Specify the tag to be deleted")
```

Once I'll use those to know what to delete when consuming my API, Is there any way to get the flag value that my user choose?

Comment: Have you read through the go flag package documentation https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#example_

Comment: Use distinct variables for each flag. If you put them all into the same value you can't distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution has very bad design... You do not know order of eveluating those flags.

### The issue

I am assuming you are using `cobra`. So when you read documentation you will not find any part of how your flags are evaluated. So sometimes it is called undefined behavior and it may work but if the future it may be changed

Let's analyze your example:

```
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "wallet", "w", "", "Specify the wallet to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "holding", "o", "", "Specify the holding to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "ticker", "t", "", "Specify the ticker to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&option, "tag", "g", "", "Specify the tag to be deleted")
```

You have the following flags: `wallet, holding, ticker, tag`. We can assume order is how you put it in your code. Let's say potential behavior:

User put the `ticker` flag. Default value for all flags is empty. So the `option` variable has an empty value, which comes from the `tag` flag.

### The solution

You should use separated variable for each flag. And you should implement your logic to cover the part to determine which flag has been put.

```
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&wallet, "wallet", "w", "", "Specify the wallet to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&holding, "holding", "o", "", "Specify the holding to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&ticker, "ticker", "t", "", "Specify the ticker to be deleted")
deleteCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&tag, "tag", "g", "", "Specify the tag to be deleted")

if wallet != "" {
    option = wallet
    selected = "wallet"
} else if holding != "" {
    option = holding
    selected = "holding"
} else ...
...
...
```

Comment: That was great! Actually I was trying to avoid the If/Else chain to evaluate all variables, that's why I was looking for any way to parse the flag that the user chose. But your explanation is pretty clear. Thank you very much.